# Как в файле nginx.conf прочитать содержимое другого текстового файла?

Tags: nginx, config, http-server, geoip

В `nginx.conf` настроил доступ по `GeoIP`. Список запрещенных стран получился слишком длинным и писать это все в файл конфигураций не совсем логично. Хотел уточнить, можно ли этот список стран вынести в отдельный `.txt` файл и считать его в том месте, где он мне нужен в `nginx.conf`.

```java
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
    map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
        default no;
        FK no;
        FM no;
        EH no;
        ТУТ БУДЕТ ЕЩЕ СПИСОК СТРАН!!!! ЗАМЕНИТЬ НА СЧИТКУ ИЗ ФАЙЛА!
    }
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map параметр include

Comment: Ну и никто не мешает весь этот блок `map` писать в отдельном файле и включать  в конфиг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутрь блока map включите директиву `include`.
См документацию http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: сделал без map вовсе. В нужном месте всего лишь прописал `include /path/file`. Файл сам считался.